# Replace CPU of HP server

Tags: hardware, central-processing-unit, upgrade

Suppose we have a problem with a processor or would like to replace to a more powerful one. Is it possible? I found one article that explain the process for DL385 but not sure if this is only for a new server defective processor replacement.

Comment: Which model and generation of server are you interested in upgrading?

Comment: DL380 G6 and DL380 G7

Comment: My answer has been updated...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the model of server. However, each HP server model has option and upgrade parts available. For instance, if you had an [HP ProLiant DL380 G6](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13234_div/13234_div.HTML#Overview), you'd be able to install any of the processors listed in the [option parts list](http://h18000.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13234_div/13234_div.HTML#Core%20Options). I've done this in the past where I'd have a 4-core CPU and needed to move to dual 6-core CPUs. It's entirely supported.

Edit: Since you mentioned the ProLiant [DL380 G6](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13234_div/13234_div.html#Core%20Options) and [DL380 G7](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/13595_na/13595_na.HTML#Core%20Options), you have a lot of options. Many of the CPUs are interchangeable between the models.

Here's what I'd recommend. For the DL380 G7, the following CPUs are compatible. The models in **bold** are also compatible as upgrades for the DL380 G6.

Six-Core Processors

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5690 (3.46GHz/6-core/12MB/130W) Processor Kit 633410-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5680 (3.33GHz/6-core/12MB/130W) Processor Kit 587498-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5675 (3.06GHz/6-core/12MB/95W) Processor Kit  633414-B21

**HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5670 (2.93GHz/6-core/12MB/95W) Processor Kit    587493-B21**

**HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5660 (2.80GHz/6-core/12MB/95W) Processor Kit    587491-B21**

**HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5650 (2.66GHz/6-core/12MB/95W) Processor Kit    587482-B21**

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5649 (2.53GHz/6-core/12MB/80W) Processor Kit  633418-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5645 (2.40GHz/6-core/12MB/80W) Processor Kit  633420-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® L5640 (2.26GHz/6-core/12MB/60W) Processor Kit  587507-B21

Quad-Core Processors

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5687 (3.60GHz/4-core/12MB/130W) Processor Kit 633412-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® X5672 (3.20GHz/4-core/12MB/95W) Processor Kit  633416-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5640 (2.66GHz/4-core/12MB/80W) Processor Kit  587480-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5630 (2.53GHz/4-core/12MB/80W) Processor Kit  587478-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5620 (2.40GHz/4-core/12MB/80W) Processor Kit  587476-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5606 (2.13GHz/4-core/8MB/80W) Processor Kit   633442-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® E5603 (1.60GHz/4-core/4MB/80W) Processor Kit   633444-B21

HP DL380 G7 Intel® Xeon® L5630 (2.13GHz/4-core/12MB/40W) Processor Kit  587505-B21

Comment: I kwow this list. 2017 year question... some trops in internet, DL380G7 accept octa core Xeon (not listed in year of release). True or false?

Comment: I've never seen an 8-core CPU in a DL380 G7 HP ProLiant.

Comment: note: newer list show X5667 4core/8threads (not listed in older materials) https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02873427&docLocale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are replaceable... The QuickSpecs detail the processors available for each server.